# Pyrex that can be used in an instant pot

Tags: equipment

What pyrex would be suitable for pressure steaming in an Instant Pot (also known as 'Pot in Pot' cooking)?  I am a new user and want to make sure I have the correct cookware.

Comment: @Jolenealaska _Steaming is a different function on the Instant Pot, there's even a button labeled "steaming" and it implies not using pressure._ The steam button on at least some instant pots is steaming under pressure. See page 15 of https://instantpot.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/DUO-Series-Manual-English-July-21-2017-Low-Res.pdf

Answer (score 10):

That is commonly done, and yes, any pyrex is fine for it although metal has an advantage in that it wouldn't require extra time. Anytime you use glass, pyrex, ceramic or any other heat absorbent material for "pot in pot" cooking, add ~5 minutes to the time under pressure. Anything that is safe to use in the oven is safe to use in the Instant Pot.  Whatever you use inside the liner of the Instant Pot as your cooking vessel, use the trivet and add water (at least 1 1/2 cups or so) to the inner pot of the Instant Pot, and be sure there is some room (it doesn't need to be much) to allow steam to pass between your inner pot and the Instant Pot liner.

[Here's more](https://instantpot3.wordpress.com/2016/06/25/pip/) on the subject of 'pot in pot' cooking.

Comment: So since this is steaming, even though a bowl will be safe, a basket might well be better for a lot of things, where you don't want all the water to collect in your food?

Comment: @Jefromi A basket may be better for some items, but condensation is accounted for in recipes that use the "pot in pot" method. I do grits *PIP* for example, because they scorch on the bottom of the inner pot otherwise. I follow a recipe that calls for less water in the grits for *PIP* than it calls for if you don't use a separate vessel.

Comment: Why do you add 5 minutes to the time under pressure rather than expecting it to take 5 minutes longer to come up to pressure?  Food also absorbs heat, yet IP cooking time is not dependent on how much food of a given type you are cooking—the time under pressure for a cup of chickpeas is the same as the time for a quart.

Answer (score 3):

I am new to Instant Pot also.

Had a "chat" with Ranier at Instant Pot today to ask about glass dish to use in Instant Pot.

Was told that anything that is oven proof is okay or to use a smaller Instant Pot insert.  Mine is a six quart. I was ready to throw it out the back door last week because I was having such a hard time putting lid on.

This is going to be my favorite fun kitchen gadget.

Answer (score 3):

Manufacturers of Pyrex, Corningware, and Anchor Hocking do not recommend their products in the Instant Pot. I emailed, chat with them.

Comment: Can you link to an official citation? If so, I would think this is the right answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have a minimalist kitchen, a good option is oven-safe Glasslock, which has the advantage of also providing a convenient way to pack food for refrigeration and transport.  It's also available in a variety of stackable sizes; obviously round Glasslock will fit more efficiently in an Instant Pot than will square or rectangular.

Answer (score 1):

I am making chocolate pots de creme and also at times I like to make creme brulee so I use individual ramekins in the Instant Pot to pressure cook.

Comment: Thanks, but this was already clarified a while back, edited into the question and all. I've gone ahead and removed those obsolete comments that you were responding to. I think your suggestion of ramekins is an answer to the question, so I'll leave that here, but I'll edit out the bit that was a response to the now-deleted comments.

Answer (score 1):

So I work for Corelle, Corningware & More (who own Pyrex and we sell/work with the instant pot company. From what I know, older Pyrex might be better suited because of the way it was made. However, as a previous commenter stated, we generally do not reccomend it. Now, I work retail so there might be better answers out there as to why. However, I do use Pyrex and the corningware bakeware and personally I think that the bakeware and ramekins would likely do well. They are very durable (lol trust me I have seen them dropped on all sorts of surfaces) and they are oven safe. I think that if you choose to try one of these products for this pot-in-pot method then that's probably your best bet!

Comment: Why they don’t recommend it in general, or why older stuff would be better?   I suspect I know the answer on the older stuff— it was made from a different material which is better at handling the internal stresses you  get when you don’t hear the container evenly.  You still might have problems if you heated the base quickly before the sides had a chance to heat up. (Which would be much like heating it stovetop, which is not recommended for most Pyrex)